# Liver Server console error when updating my app.js file in VScode?

Tags: npm-live-server

Has this happened to anyone? I have been trying to fix this for hours. My port 5500 used to work perfectly and update automatically, but now when I am looking for a specific console.log in the chrome browser, it gives me this error from a 'renderer.js' file:

try {
se = void 0 === global

There is a reference error saying that 'global' is not defined.

If I 'go live' it will intially give me the correct console.log, but the above happens when I change anything in order to receive a different log.

I have tried to update everything accordingly (live server extension, vscode, browser, etc) and nothing has changed.